# Validation of viewstate MAC failed 50 times a day

Tags: asp.net, validation, viewstate

Okay so this topic is not new on the internet, i get that. But i havent been able to find a solution that fixed my problem.

Problem is i keep catching this exception on my website. Maybe 50 times a day or so. (See below for stacktrace)

Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

I have already predefined a machinekey in my web.config file - that didn't help at all.
Then i read somewhere that i could be an error caused by slow loading, but I'm logging page load times, and when this error occurs, theres nothing alarming. 
Some ppl suggest to disable the viewstate decryption, but as a lot of other ppl write, thats not really a solution.

Anyone got any idea what to do?

Stacktrace :

```
at System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowError(Exception inner, String persistedState, String errorPageMessage, Boolean macValidationError)
at System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowMacValidationError(Exception inner, String persistedState)
at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString) 
at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.System.Web.UI.IStateFormatter.Deserialize(String serializedState) 
at System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter formatter, String serializedState) 
at System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load() 
at System.Web.UI.Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium()
at System.Web.UI.Page.LoadAllState() 
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) 
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at ASP.default_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Do you run in a web farm or cluster? With multiple servers?

Comment: Have you tried capturing the failing viewstate and seeing what is in it?

Comment: I just got the error for the first time while debugging on my localhost, dont know why thought, but at least i can say that my localhost is not on a web farm. I havnt tried capturing no, but ill look into that!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a machine key into web.config

i.e.
    <system.web>
    <machineKey decryption="AES" validation="SHA1" decryptionKey="875CF3B9B54E7058CE31EAFAB05AD19400FF3DA5CDB0D324D7433C4B233B350D" validationKey="5BC50363620E53177C8E7E81BE1CF13141F860C5E41AF3EEEFC82AA37160E82D"/>

The reason is that when in a web farm the page you see may have been served by a different machine than the one you postback to and the decryption of the viewstate/cookies etc will not match up UNLESS the owner of the farm setup matching machineKeys across his farm (unlikely). In a single server environment this key is automagically generated but it never matters as the application pool always knows its own key